# explicit use of l for Long,D for Double,,F for Float in autoboxing

Tags: java

```
Byte byte1=10;
Short short1=20;
Integer integer=30;
```

In the above code autoboxing happens successfully
see the below code here I am doing casitng explicitly because It is taking 20 as integer numeric literal by default.

```
Byte byte1=new Byte((byte) 20);
Short short1=new Short((short) 20);
```

but see the below code , I have to use l,f and d explicitly without this it is showing error........what is the reason behind it.I am not getting it.

```
Long long1=40l;
Float float1=50f;
Double double1=60d;
```

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: @Joni, probably you should read the whole question, not just the code.

Comment: Looks like the reason is that a `long/double/float` literal can represent values of greater range, than a simple `int` literal does and the compiler needs a way to tell an `int` literal from a `long` one.

Comment: My bet (too lazy to search doc now) is that the int constants are being autoboxed into `Integer` (causing a `ClassCastException` when the JVM tries to assign the values to `Long` or `Float`). BTW, don't just say "showing error", please be specific.

Comment: Please could you reword your question to use clear, complete sentences (and not *In the above code autoboxing happens successfully see the below code here I am doing casitng explicitly because It is taking 20 as integer numeric literal by default* etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Auto-boxing doesn't include automatic widening of primitives.

The default type of a constant integer numeric expression in java is `int`, so those numbers are ints, which will be auto boxed to Integers if required. Automatic widening will occur when a narrower primitive type is assigned to a wider type, such as an `int` to a `long`.

But the two compiler actions will not *both* happen; that's why you need to get the primitive constant expression to the appropriate type so that the auto boxing will be to the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the [Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.2) for floating point literals, ie. `F or f` for `float`, and `D or d` for `double`

> For decimal floating-point literals, at least one digit (in either the
>   whole number or the fraction part) and either a decimal point, an
>   exponent, or a float type suffix are required.

For integers,

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).

The [unboxing conversions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8) are, among other,

```
From type long to type Long

From type float to type Float

From type double to type Double
```

So unless your types are the correct type, you cannot unbox.

As for the `Byte`, `Short`, `Integer`, the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) again comes to the rescue

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of
>   information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause
>   the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input
>   value.

In your case, an explicit cast isn't necessary because the values fall within the range of their specific type. If instead, you had

```
Byte b = 1251;
```

that would create a compilation error, solved by doing

```
Byte b = (byte)1251;
```

but losing information in the value.